# How to generate access token for drop box using the java

Tags: dropbox

I want to upload file on drop box, but I need to use the access token for the operation. Access token is expired after in few hours. So again access token is required to generate manually. So any possible way to generate access token through java code and use that token for performing the operation on drop box

For Automation perspective every time generate new access token when I run the script

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is now issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens#updating-access-token-type).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.

The [official Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java) can actually handle the process for you automatically, as long as you supply the necessary credentials, e.g., as shown retrieved in [the examples here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/authorize). For instance, for a client-side app, such as a desktop app, you should use the PKCE flow, e.g., [as shown here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/authorize/PkceAuthorize.java). That allows you to make and save a [DbxCredential with a refresh token as shown here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/authorize/AuthorizeExample.kt#L85). With that, you can make API calls [like shown here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/main/examples/examples/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/account_info/AccountInfoExample.kt#L26).